# filter asp.net healthmonitoring

Tags: asp.net, sanitization, health-monitoring

We have activated health monitoring on our website.  Recently we are getting a lot of hack attempts which are caused by bots, but also spawn a lot of server errors.

```
Exception type: System.Web.HttpException
Exception message: The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.

Request information:
Request URL: http://www.ourdomain.be/Product/Band/29360" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','7','[CUT_OUT_SOME_STUFF]row ab_button" id="am-b6" href="
User host address: ---.---.47.93
```

How can I filter these particular events so I don't get 10 emails per second?
Or how can I sanitize the URL before it is handled by the security parts of ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

I can't totally repro your error - I get an exception for Illegal characters in path instead. Nevertheless...

- Quick and dirty = send your emails to a dummy address and set up a
  filter/rule on it so only the ones you want get forwarded to you
- Slightly less quick = Use Application_Error with
  Server.GetLastError() and Server.ClearError() to inspect and ignore
  these
- Create your own health monitoring provider, though I think you still
  need to use Server.GetLastError to retrieve the exception data. See
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Application_error doesn't trigger because it's apparently the ASP.Net pipeline which catches it before.  Have now similar errors: "ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL."